# Minimal sufficient statistics for normal distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have the following variables $X_1,..,X_n,Y_1,..,Y_m$ with distribution $X_i\sim N(\mu,\sigma_1^2), Y_j\sim N(\mu,\sigma_2^2)$  that are all iid. How do I find the minimal sufficient statistic for $(\mu,\sigma_1^2,\sigma_2^2)$?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2781483/edit) the question. [This](http://goo.gl/xQWVb) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: There are several ways to solve this, but one way you can find the answer is by first finding the joint density of $(X,Y)$, call this $f_{XY}(x,y)$. (Use iid) Then let $(x,y)$ and $(x*,y*)$ be two $n+m $ x 1 vectors. Find the likelihood ratio, $L(x,y;\mu, \sigma_1, \sigma_2) = \frac{f_{XY}(x,y; \mu, \sigma_1, \sigma_2)}{f_{XY}(x*, y*; \mu, \sigma_1, \sigma_2)}$. You can pick out the sufficient statistics in order for $L$ to not depend on the parameters. I’m pulling from a theorem from http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat705/Lecture5.pdf section 3.5, theorem 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Neyman-Pearson factorization criteria, i.e.,
\begin{align}
& L(\mu, \sigma_1^2, \sigma_2^2; Z=(X_1,..,X_n, Y_1,...,Y_m))  & \\
&=\frac{1}{\sigma_1^{n} \sigma_2^m (2\pi)^{(n+m)/2}}\exp\{\left(
\sigma_2^2\sum_{i=1}^n(Z_i-\mu)^2  + \sigma_1^2\sum_{j=n+1}^{n+m}(Z_j-\mu)^2 \right)/(2\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2) 
\},
\end{align}

so the MSS for the vector $\theta = (\mu, \sigma_1^2, \sigma_2^2)$, is
$$
T(X) = (\frac{1}{m+n}\sum_{i=1}^{m+n}Z_i,S_n^2, S_m^2),
$$
where
$S_i^2 =  \frac{1}{n_i}\sum(X_i - \bar{X})^2$, which is the MLE of the $i$th group, $i=n,m$.